# Setting a QComboBox as a QTableWidget Column Header

Tags: c++, qt, combobox, qtablewidget

I'd like to be able to set a QComboBox as a column **header** inside my QTableWidget.

The closest thing I've found is something similar to

```
QComboBox * combo = new QComboBox;
combo->addItem("100");
combo->addItem("200");
combo->addItem("300");

m_table->setCellWidget(0, 0, combo);
```

But this just sets the `0, 0` cell to have the combo box, not the actual header.

The code I'd *like* to work:

```
m_table->setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, combo); // does not compile
```

Currently:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Is this even possible?

Comment: See if this helps: ["Qt Support Weekly #27 – Widgets on a header"](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2012/09/28/qt-support-weekly-27-widgets-on-a-header/)